# Eliminar commit de github

Tags: git, github

Como dice el titulo, como puedo borrar un commit de github intente `git reset --hard <commit>` pero no funciono, hay alguna forma?

Comment: Como te han indicado la solución es, una vez tengas el repositorio local en la forma que a ti te gusta, hacer un `git push -f` para forzar la reescritura del repositorio remoto. **Sin embargo** esto no debería hacerse si ese repositorio es compartido con otros desarrolladores. Al menos no sin antes avisarles de que van a tener problemas en su próximo pull, pues al reescribir la historia del remoto ésta quedará incompatible con sus historias locales.

Comment: https://www.campusmvp.es/recursos/post/como-eliminar-el-ultimo-commit-de-git-en-el-repositorio-de-origen-p-ej-github.aspx aquí tienes una ayuda, espero que te sirva

Answer (score 1):

Si estas trabajando en un repositorio, haces cambios, realizas un commit para guardarlos en la historia y lo envias al remoto usando push. Luego te das cuenta de que va con un error y queres echarte para atrás.
En primer lugar destruimos el commit localmente con:

> git reset HEAD^ --hard

y a continuación forzando los cambios al repositorio remoto de origen con:

> git push origin -f

Answer (score 0):

El comando que has usado es correcto para borrarlo en `git` pero si ya habías subido los cambios a Github, entonces después del `reset --hard` debes de hacer:

`git push origin HEAD --force`